# How to make the login and register work with the code below

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am working on a laravel webshop and I have some problems with the Authentication, login and register. First of all, if I try to login with my email and password, who are already registered in the database, it will say "These credentials do not match our records." So it doesn't recognize my data. If I will navigate to the page it will actually recognize my email.

If I try to register it doesn't do anything.

I already have tried to do `php artisan make:auth` again but that won't change anything. Also, I have checked my models as following: I did some `dd();` in the validator and in the `create(){}` but the `dd();` will not launch in the create function so I suppose the create function isn't triggered.

//Login controller:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{


    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

//Register controller:

```
 protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'gebruikersnaam' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 
            'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'voornaam' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'achternaam' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'telefoonnummer' => ['required', 'string','min:9' ,'max:255'],
            'klant_afbeelding' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        ]);
    }

 1. /**
         * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
         *
         * @param  array  $data
         * @return \App\User
         */

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'gebruikersnaam' => $data['gebruikersnaam'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'voornaam' => $data['voornaam'],
            'achternaam' => $data['achternaam'],
            'telefoonnummer' => $data['telefoonnummer'],
            'klant_afbeelding' => $data['klant_afbeelding'],
        ]);
    }
```

//User class:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'gebruikersnaam', 'email', 'password','voornaam','achternaam',
        'telefoonnummer','klant_afbeelding'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

}
```

//My routes:

```
<?php  
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

// Route::get('/', function (Request $request) {
//      $data = $request->validate([
//         'message' => 'required|max:255',
//         'rating' => 'required|url|max:255',
//     ]);
//
//     return view('home');
// });

Route::get('/Profiel', 'ProfielController@Profiel');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@Home' );

// route voor de review submit
Route::resource('reviewSubmit', 'ReviewController');


Route::get('/Profiel', 'ProfielController@Profiel');

Route::post('/profielupdate', 'ProfielController@update');

Route::post('/niewsbriefsubscribe', 'HomeController@subscribe');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

//Login view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

//Register view

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                            @csrf

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="gebruikersnaam" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Gebruikersnaam') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                    @error('gebruikersnaam')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                    @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="voornaam" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Voornaam') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="voornaam" type="text" class="form-control @error('voornaam') is-invalid @enderror" name="voornaam" value="{{ old('voornaam') }}" required autocomplete="voornaam">

                                    @error('voornaam')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="achternaam" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Achternaam') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="achternaam" type="text" class="form-control @error('achternaam') is-invalid @enderror" name="achternaam" value="{{ old('achternaam') }}" required autocomplete="achternaam">

                                    @error('achternaam')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="telefoonnummer" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Telefoonnummer') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="telefoonnummer" type="text" class="form-control @error('telefoonnummer') is-invalid @enderror" name="telefoonnummer" value="{{ old('telefoonnummer') }}" required autocomplete="telefoonnummer">

                                    @error('telefoonnummer')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="wachtwoord" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Wachtwoord') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                    @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Registreer') }}
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

The expected thing to happen is that i can register and actually save in the database and logging in.

The output at the moment is the opposite.

Comment: have you create it with command ?

Comment: Yes, in the terminal. After that i updated the models myself.

Comment: "if I try to login with my email and password, who are already registered in the database" - how did you register the user?

Comment: I made a function just to fill the database with random users. At forgot password it will actually reconize the user / email from the database.

Comment: @JelmerHilhorst Did you hash the passwords when you created the users?

Comment: @DelenaMalan Aah no i didn't hash them. Would that fix it then?

Comment: @DelenaMalan i have hashed them now. Still doens't work

Comment: @JelmerHilhorst Have you checked you log file for any errors? Should be in the `storage/logs` directory.

Comment: @DelenaMalan No errors relative to these problems

Comment: I'm guessing your views aren't calling your register and login functions then. Could you add some of your views' code here?

Comment: @DelenaMalan Here you go :) Added the login and register views above.

Comment: pls update the route, it's not well define.
you can define it mmanualy or not but you must have something like that :
$this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');

Comment: read more about that here : https://www.5balloons.info/laravel-authentication-tutorial-login-logout-register-forgot-password-remember-me-functionality/

Comment: @SteveRuben Allright the login works! Thankyou. I also tried this for the register but it still doesn't work.

Comment: $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
   $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

Comment: @SteveRuben Doesn't work.

Comment: have you read the tuto ?

Comment: @SteveRuben Yes i did

Comment: $this->get('register', 'Auth\LoginController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register'); $this->post('register', 'Auth\LoginController@register');

Comment: have you a register controller ?

Comment: @SteveRuben Yes i have see the code above!